# How to select rows when the exact Ids match

Tags: sql-server

```
userId  Username TypeId StateId
229    Test name   52   2
229    Test name   52   4
229    Test name   53   2
229    Test name   53   4
238    Test name2  52   2
238    Test name2  53   2
```

Hi All, From the above table I'd like return only that matches Typeid(52,53) and stateId(2,4)
The results should not return Test name2. Because it doesn't have selected stateid 4. Please suggest the query

```
select  userId,Appraiser,PropertyTypeId,StateId  from vw_SuggestedAppraisersWithSchedule 
where P PropertyTypeId in (52,53)  and stateid in (2,4)
group by UserId,Appraiser,PropertyTypeId,StateId Having count(propertytypeId)=2 and having count(stateid)=2
```

Excepted result:

```
userId  Username TypeId StateId
229    Test name   52   2
229    Test name   52   4
229    Test name   53   2
229    Test name   53   4
```

Each user should have TypeId data (52,53) and StateId (2,4) rows data

Thank you,

Comment: Please clarify with your epected results for the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a correlation using *exists*:

```
select userid, username, TypeId, StateId 
from t
where StateId in (2,4) and TypeId in (52,53)
and exists(
  select * from t t2 
  where t2.userid = t.userid and t2.stateid != t.stateid
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it doesn't work as expected. It should pull users who has selected only 2 and 4 stated in their profile.